# Cannot download from AWS to RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubymine

I'm trying to synchronize a Rails app on AWS with my local Mac for development.

I'm using RubyMine. I setup the Deployment configuration successfully and am able to browse/SSH into the remote server just fine. However, when I try to download from the remote server using `Tools -> Deployment -> Download from AWS` I just get a prompt saying `No files or folders found to process`.

Would appreciate any insights. I'm also new to working on a remote server locally, so if this is not the ideal way of doing things, please feel free to point me towards a related blog post/article.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to work on a remote server locally instead of just working locally then pushing when you are ready?

Comment: @TallPaul Both would work for me, right now it doesn't let me open remote files from the remote browser or download them locally.

Comment: Can you log into AWS? I am assuming you are keeping your files in S3? Is this code that you are storing up there?

Comment: The code and the dev environment is setup on an EC2 instance. I can SSH into it and see the files in the remote browser in RubyMine. I hope that helps.

Comment: I have done something like this before on a different project. I put all of my code in a repository, such as github and cloned that repository to my local machine. When I was ready I would ssh into the EC2 and have a folder that was linked to that same repository and all I would have to do was a git pull and that would update all of the code on the EC2, and if it is a rails project you just run the restart command and you should be good to go. Does that make sense?\

Comment: Please collect detailed logs and look for error message: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202.